# GDAL Warp cuttline not working

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

Has anyone ever got the cutline to work in C++?

I have it working off the command line no problem, but it doesn't seem to do anything when I populate that argument in C++ as below:

```
*//Create a OGRGeometry variable
OGRGeometry *thisGeom;
//parse an input WKT to char*
char* wktIn = (char*) pIn_wkt_geom;
//Create and polulate thisGeom with the input WKT geometry
OGRErr err = OGRGeometryFactory::createFromWkt(&wktIn, poSRS, &thisGeom);

//Add thisGeom as the cutline argument psWarpOptions->hCutline = thisGeom;*
```

Comment: GDAL is written in C++ so I would rather believe that there is something wrong in your code. Perhaps the source code of gdalwarp could help in finding the correct use http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdalwarp.cpp.